# Is there a service for recurring buying of Monero every 2 weeks?

Tags: exchange

I know Coinbase has the ability to buy BTC, LTC, and ETH on a recurring set time. But is there a service that can do this for Monero? I don't care what the price is, but I just want to buy monero every week as a way to dollar cost average.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You find an exchange where you can set up buying an order every week. Not really sure but i think that at [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com) this could work.
2. You create an account on an exchange, get API keys from them and execute the API call to create a buy order every week. If you really want to automate this, you could set up a python script (or any other programming language) on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) (which you don't have to pay) and let that execute periodically.